# How do I hide the bottom status bar on the Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android, android-statusbar, samsung-galaxy

I couldn't find the way to hide (programaticaly or manually) the bottom status bar (back, home, active apps, and screen capture) of Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 3.1. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

> is that possible???

No, sorry. Without the system bar, the user cannot exit your app.

Comment: well, thanks for the reply. I thing it's a seious android bug anyway...,.,